# Stuck on an error in Python 3 (exceptions, loop)

Tags: python, exception, loops, while-loop

So what I'm trying to do here is that if you put in a string instead of an integer, you go back to the start

But for some reason, the program just stops when you put in a string

```
while True:
    try:
        print("Will select a random number between selected limits: 'x' and 'y'")
        x = int(input("x = "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number")
        break
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while True:
    try:
        print("Will select a random number between selected limits: 'x' and 'y'")
        x = int(input("x = "))
        y = int(input("y = "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number") # don't break here, let loop repeat
    else:
        break # only break when there is no error
```

Comment: What's the point of putting the `break` in the `else:` block, rather than in the end of the `try:` block?

Comment: @chenaren just a matter of personal style, I thought it felt more sequential this way

Comment: my program was actually done, i was just polishing it a bit. i had the y = int(input()) done already and everything, but you just simplified it for me by 10-20 lines and everything works now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter, by one line ;):

```
while True:
    try:
        print("Will select a random number between selected limits: 'x' and 'y'")
        x = int(input("x = "))
        y = int(input("y = "))
        break # only break when there is no error
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a number") # don't break here, let loop repeat
```